# Using colorpicker in creating a wordpress widget

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I am creating a widget and had successfully created it, what I want to achieve is that on the widget form, I want to add an option where the user can select a color for the font. Thus, I've placed a textbox and when the user clicks on the textbox a colorpicker will appear.

I have not tried doing that in the past and I've searched google for any help but instead they want me to download their plugins and etc.

I don't need any plugin or whatsoever, I just want a simple colorpicker implementation.

ANy help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This colorpicker is **built into wordpress**](http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/). Simply follow the implementation guide and you're Good To Go.

**edit** It would seem something is wrong with the site, as it causes frequenty crashes in FF 5. Sorry, I can't find any other site that has the documentation, either. Use Chrome or IE9 and it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good one that I've used: http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

That might be of help to you.